# grub says: "attempting to decrypt master key" on every boot

Tags: grub2, luks

The system is recently upgraded to 21.10
Every boot starts with this simple text message.
I need to enter the LUKS passphrase.
Once done .. it boots as before, and with the nice GUI, asks again for the LUKS passphrase.

This issue appaered after using a grub tool to update grub with new kernel, because after the 20.10 upgrade, I still had grub with a kernel from 19.xx or so kernel.

Please help me restore "normal" boot - straight to graphic LUKS passphrase question.

[image: every boot I see this:]

[image: partitions]

Comment: have you tried the "ESC" button?  (No, no sarcasm in my comment - sometimes one can accidentally hit the ESC button and it goes to a terminal, re-hitting it normally* solves the problem)

Comment: Yes, ESC gives:
error: Passphrase not supplied
error: no such cryptodisk found
error: disk 'lvid/evlalh-..........  ............ not found
Entering Rescue mode...
grub rescue>

Comment: Try removing `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` in `/etc/default/grub` if you have that. Overall, very little info is provided in this question

Comment: Thank you  - by the time, I reinstalled, and can't confirm if that fixed it.

Comment: It's probably caused by an encryption key you set during the installation. Just type the pass key and press and enter.might take some time. But Worked for me